# Effect plot contradicting regression coefficient

Tags: regression, treatment-effect

Among other parameters, I examined the effect of the factor $Q$ on the response variable $Y$. I found a linear model with $R^2$ and adjusted $R^2$ being around $0.95$. The $F$ statistic of the overall model is significant at $0.01$ level. The coefficient, $\beta_Q$ for $Q$ is also significant. For this question what matters is that $\beta_Q < 0$. So, **the model suggests that increasing $Q$ should decrease $Y$.**

However, when I plot $Y$ against $Q$, I see the opposite: **$Y$ is increasing as $Q$ is increasing.** The following figure depicts changes of the mean of $Y$ over three levels of $Q$:

[image]

I used R's `lm` to fit the model. How to resolve this issue?

Comment: What else is in the model? If $\beta_Q$ is the marginal effect after controlling for other stuff then it is totally plausible that the direction of the effect might flip once other variables are included. See [Simpson's Paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simpson%27s_paradox)

Comment: There are six more variables, each of them having the coefficient between twice and thrice the value of $\beta_Q$ in terms of absolute values. All of them are significant at $0.01$ value, too. I wasn't aware of Simpon's paradox, thanks for the link. I will read the article. :)

Comment: @GabrielFGeislerMesevage If I understood correctly, the way to resolve this is to let "story, not data, dictate choices". Interpretation based on the figure has more sense than the one arising from the sign of $\beta_Q$. Can I adopt the former on this basis?

Comment: If Q is genuinely a factor with three levels you should get more than one coefficient.

Comment: How do you mean that $Q$ should have more than one coefficient, @mdewey? Do you have in mind including $Q^2$?

Comment: You state that it is a factor by which I understood a categorical variable so with three levels it would be represented by two dummy variables thus giving rise to two coefficients.

Comment: No, it is numerical.